# Separate AWS accounts based on the projects or based on the environments?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have one project (include all environments) in one AWS account. I'm gonna start a new project so I've made a new AWS account. But I'm wondering if it's better to isolate the projects or the environments (like one account for the whole test envs of projects and one for prod envs)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a complex subject and I'm not sure you're going to get a clear answer, because "it depends". Do your projects have particular regulatory requirements (PCI, HIPAA, etc)? Does your company or client have a particular policy or infosec approach?

Comment: @kojiro As far as I know, they don't save very secinfo like credit card,... The environments for each project would not be very huge. For example for one project, it has 15 instances include all env which is in one aws account. But wouldn't it be safer to separate test(dev) from prod env? in case if by accsident something change? or separating projects would be fine?

Comment: It is definitely safer to separate test and production accounts. It can also be beneficial to separate accounts by project for billing purposes. Perhaps you need multiple dev/prod accounts per each project. There is no "best" or "correct" answer to your question, so it's probably going to be closed as "too broad". It sounds like you are asking the right questions, and you need to simply evaluate what is best for your specific scenario.

Comment: Both options are viable (projects/envrionment separation), but its always a question of the overhead created by these kind of operational efforts and finding the sweet spot between putting all your eggs in one basket and segregating your resources so much you spend too much time managing them. I would prioritize environment before projects as production-based permissions tend to be more critical then project-based permissions.